# Is there a way I can queue exactly 1 message per second sqs to trigger lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, serverless

I want to hit an api with rate limit of 1 call per second and do it using sqs or any serverless approach.

So if I send 100 message to sqs queue can I set to trigger a lambda function from sqs that runs once every second  or any other approach do it without maintaining a database ?

Comment: Frankly, it would probably be easier to run a small Amazon EC2 instance and have a program sleep between executions. I don't know what sort of processing you're doing, but a `t4g.nano` is under half a cent per hour (10 cents per day) and would probably be an easier-to-manage solution than trying to time Lambda executions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger lambda and not restricted to use SQS, you can create an AWS Cloudwatch event rule and schedule it to trigger lambda every 1 minute as cron.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not using only Lambda and SQS.
My first thought was using CloudWatch events, but the units on the rates only goes down to one minute.

I will say scheduling something to run every second might also be a bit flaky so you might miss a few seconds here and there.

One way to potentially do this is using AWS Step Functions. The documentation has an example where they are polling a Lambda function continuously every x seconds to see if a job is done, you could set that up in an infinite loop. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-job-poller.html

However I am concerned about what that will end up costing you. I think we need to know more about what you are trying to do instead of how you are trying to do it to be able to help you better.

Step functions with a state transition every second will cost you at least 65 dollars per month. Twice if this counts as two state transitions, so at that point you are probably better off having a simple server polling for 1 SQS message every second.